# Exponents and mod arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Is it true that if $a\equiv b \bmod n$, the $c^a \equiv c^b \bmod n$? I'm not quite sure how to prove this myself.

Comment: Why are you writing $a$ $\equiv$ $b$ instead of $a\equiv b$?  I've seen a bunch of people doing that lately, and now I'm wondering if there some sort of software you find on the web somewhere that tells you to do things that way?  It causes neglect of proper spacing.

Comment: @arbautjc : Look at the MathJax code in the two expressions I wrote and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: "dollars $a$ dollars dollars \equiv dollars dollars $b$ dollars"… instead of… "dollars $a$ \equiv $b$ dollars".

Comment: Ah, ok, I understand now ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample:

$$3\equiv0 \mod 3$$

But

$$2^3 \not \equiv 2^0 \mod 3$$

Comment: More dramatically, (but for the same reason :P ) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem

Comment: That was my first thought, but I found it maybe too difficult for a first encounter with congruences. And it could give the impression that it requires some work to find a counterexample.

Comment: Oh definitely. An explicit example was the right way to answer this question :) Just wanted to point it out. (if I was writing, I would written my comment in parentheses at the end)

Answer (score 1):

You've seen in other answers (*mixedmath*'s and *arbautjc*'s, for example) that this isn't true.  However, there is something similar that is true.

For a **PRIME** $n$ and integer $m$, we have,

$$a = b + m(n-1)$$

implies

$$c^a \equiv c^b \mod n$$

Answer (score -1):

A counterexample:

Consider when $n = 15$, and $2 \equiv 17 \bmod 15$. Then $2^2 \equiv 4 \bmod 15$ compared to $2^{17} \equiv 2 \bmod 15$ (and this last one is easy because $2^8 \equiv 1 \bmod 15$ by Euler's theorem).